# What can it be that causes the error "List index out of bounds (..)" after upgrading from Delphi 11.1 to 11.2?

Tags: delphi

Only since the upgrade I got the subjected error, and after pressing the Details-button in the error message it shows:

```
[6F6A815B]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.TList.Get (Line 5108, "System.Classes.pas" + 2) + $A
[7119EC97]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.GetAppEvents (Line 686, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 1) + $B
[7119E5BE]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.DoActivate (Line 438, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 5) + $9
[7114362F]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.WndProc (Line 11035, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 140) + $C
[6F6C580C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18490, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[71D85883]{vclide280.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TVirtualTreeHintWindow.IsHintMsg (Line 7121, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 7) + $13
[7114417F]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11460, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[711441C2]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 11490, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[71144501]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 11629, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 27) + $3
[00B98082]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 227, "" + 16) + $2
```

I did not add any code since my programs run normally, except when exiting the error appears. Apparently, at that point the debugger is already closed.
Apart from a series of GetIt libraries and components, Spring4D is the only third-party software from an external source.
The GetIt plugins:

```
    Bookmarks-11-1.6.3
    Essentials-2022.06-D11
    JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2022.02
    JEDIVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-2022.02
    LockBox-2021.11-11
    ParallelDebugger-11-1.0.3
    ParnassusCoreEditor-11-1.6.3
    PNGComponents-2021.11-11
    PowerPDF-2021.09-11
    Python4Delphi-1.0
```

Comment: Likely a defect in your code. Either show [mcve], or better, debug your program

Comment: Did you install any plugins via GetIt in Delphi 11.1?

Comment: There is an amazing lack of detail here. No information about when the issue occurs, no code, nothing useful at all. You're going to have to provide much more detail if you expect to get help here. You should review [ask] and [mre] and then come back and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Embarcadero keep backward compatibility in runtime bpls, but made changes into design time bpls when doing minor upgrading from 11.1 to 11.2. Seems like you have installed some third party components, which were not rebuilt for the 11.2 version. Take your time. Developers will rebuild it or Embarcadero will make some patch to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean "backward compatibility"?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Thanks to you, we got it right.

Comment: Indeed, I believe that this must be indeed the case. It needs some time.
The only third-party software that I have installed from an external source is Spring4D, apart from a bunch of GetIt software from within Delphi. I cloned and installed the latest version of Spring4D, but probably that is not 11.2-ready as yet. Thanks for your nice reply.